# Why is the restart inittab action asking me for an id?

Tags: shell, init-script, init

I am following the [NAND firmware update](http://wiki.thincan.org/NAND_firmware_update) tutorial to try to get my system to run from RAM so I can flash it. I previously had my script running but for some reason unknown to me it is giving me:

```
INIT: /etc/inittab[44]: missing id field
```

It worked perfectly fine before and I can't seem to pick out why inittab only just recently started asking me for an id field for the restart action.

Any idea why I could be getting this error message? Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

NOTE: When `kill -HUP 1` is run I get the error on this line in my `inittab`:

```
::restart:/reS
```

The following is my script that I am trying to use to update my flash

```
NEWROOTDIR=/tmp/newroot
mkdir -p ${NEWROOTDIR}
mount -t tmpfs none ${NEWROOTDIR}

cd /
echo Copying existing file system ...
echo Copying bin ...
cp -a bin ${NEWROOTDIR}
echo Copying dev ...
cp -a dev ${NEWROOTDIR}
echo Copying etc ...
cp -a etc ${NEWROOTDIR}
echo Copying lib ...
cp -a lib ${NEWROOTDIR}
echo Copying sbin ...
cp -a sbin ${NEWROOTDIR}
echo Copying usr ...
cp -a usr ${NEWROOTDIR}
echo Copying home ...
cp -a home ${NEWROOTDIR}
echo Done copying existing file system


echo Creating folders
mkdir ${NEWROOTDIR}/root
mkdir ${NEWROOTDIR}/proc
mkdir ${NEWROOTDIR}/sys
mkdir ${NEWROOTDIR}/oldroot

echo Killing all system processes
killall5 -9
echo Rebinding /proc to the new root
mount --bind /proc ${NEWROOTDIR}/proc

echo Pivoting to new root
cd ${NEWROOTDIR}
/sbin/pivot_root . oldroot
cd /
echo Cleaning up inittab
grep -v restart /oldroot/etc/inittab > /etc/inittab

echo Inserting the restart command into inittab
echo "::restart:/reS" >> /etc/inittab 
echo "umount /oldroot" >> /reS
echo "/usr/sbin/ubiformat ${mtd_fs} -f /oldroot/var/volatile/tmp/fs.img  -O 2048" >> /reS
chmod 777 /reS
echo Killing HUP
kill -HUP 1
sleep 1
echo killing QUIT
echo Restarting
kill -QUIT 1
sleep 5
```

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the error about that line missing the id field because, well, it's missing the id field.

From the [`inittab(5)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?inittab+5) manpage:

> An  entry  in  the  inittab file has the following format:
>
> ```
>  id:runlevels:action:process
> ```
>
> Lines beginning with '#' are ignored.
>
> ```
>  id     is a unique sequence of 1-4 characters which identifies an entry
>         in inittab […]
> ```

Its possible that you recently added the malformed line, or that maybe you were previous running a version of init that didn't notice. Or that you didn't notice the message, or possibly that the message wasn't logged correctly.

In any case, the fix is simple: add an id.

[Note: your line has other problems too. Its missing runlevels. I'm not sure what the "restart" action is, maybe it should be "respawn". And is it really "reS" instead of "rcS"? ]

Comment: The part I am confused about though is that in the tutorial he uses the "restart" action without the "id". What id should I be entering if I want that shell script to be started "instead of init as PID1" (This is the functionality that is described in that tutorial.) Would it matter what id I choose?

Comment: I guess you were right, I changed the action to 'once' instead of 'restart' (which doesn't seem to be documented anywhere),changed the `id` to `mine`, and removed the killall5. It successfully ran the `ubiformat` I needed after `kill -HUP 1`. Thanks for the help